Secret message from a kitten (definitely not a cosmic horror from beyond time)

Can you decrypt this secret message?
Transcript:
Just some kitten spreading love and cuteness :Dh ❤️  
ust some kitTen spreAding love and CutenessJ :Dn ❤️❤️  
st some kitton spreading love and cutenessJu :Dh ❤️❤️  
t some kitten spreading kove and cutenessJus :Dh ❤️  
some kitten spreading love and cutenessJust :Dh   
ome kitten spreading love and cutenessJusts :Dh ❤️  
me kitten spreading love and cutenessJustso :Dh ❤️❤️  
 e kitten spreading love and cutenessJustsom :Dh ❤️❤️  
  kitten spreading love and cutenessJustsome :Dh ❤️  
 itten spreading love and cutenessJustsomek :Dh   
n mod(10) + \lfloor \frac{n}{10} \rfloor  

4   |5 |36.|7  |8.   |X|10.|37.  |?  
14|37|20|24|31|9 |13|37  
4  |33|2  |16|10|34|1 |1  

